# List<Object> from 2 unrelated objects only show one object as result

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, postman, nativequery

I want to show the result in Postman from 2 unrelated objects using native queries as below:

```
    @Query(value = "select * from product p where p.id like concat('%', :productId, '%') ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Product> findProductById(String productId);

    @Query(value = "select * from customer c where c.id like concat('%',:id,'%')", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Customer> findCustomerById(String id);
```

and I'd like to add their results with conditions:

- if productId is empty, I only want to show result from  `List<Customer>`, and vice versa
- if both are empty/not, it should show the result from both queries, product and customer as shown below:

```
    @Override
    public List<Object> findById(String customerId, String productId) {
        List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<>();
        if(customerId.isEmpty()){
            obj.addAll(productRepository.findProductById(productId));
        } else if(productId.isEmpty()){
            obj.addAll(customerRepository.findCustomerById(customerId));
        } else {
            obj.addAll(productRepository.findProductById(productId));
            obj.addAll(customerRepository.findCustomerById(customerId));
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

and this is my controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/custom")
    public List<Object> findById(@RequestParam(name = "customer") String customer, @RequestParam(name = "product") String product){
        return service.findById(customer, product);
    }
```

However, in Postman when both are empty they only show results from  `List<Product>`. Is there any way to show both?

Answer (score 0):

You can use map for this ?
Simply  use the map instead of List and you will be good to go.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
list.add("key1_value1");
list.add("key1_value2");
foo.put("key1",list);
List<Customer> list2 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
list2.add("key1_value1");
list2.add("key1_value2");
foo.put("key2",list2);
```